# Add two numbers using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Since I am a total beginner in MFC I need a help to understand some basics. At the moment it is not clear to me how can I grab some value (by ID or something else) and use it, or change it...

Lets say I have something like this:

[image]

The ID of edit boxes are: `IDC_EDIT1`, `IDC_EDIT2`, `IDC_EDIT3` (respectively).

The ID of Calculate button is `IDC_BUTTON1`.

How can I grab the value of `IDC_EDIT1`, and add it to `IDC_EDIT2` and then show it `IDC_EDIT3` on Calculate click?

After creating this Dialog, I get the following code:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

}


void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1()
{

}


void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit2()
{

}


void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit3()
{

}
```

Comment: You need to obtain the Edits values, convert to numbers, calculate, convert the result back to (MFC specific?) string and then set the third Edit value.

Comment: [Dialog Data Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange) explains, how to hook up instance variables to controls, and have them reflect the current state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starter, try this:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
   int a = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT1);
   int b = GetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT2);
   SetDlgItemInt(IDC_EDIT3, a+b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An MFC CDialog is a CWnd (inheritance). So you can access its childs with `GetDlgItem`. If you only want to process integers, you can even use the helper method `GetDlgItemInt` which will give you the text of the CEdit as an integer. Once this is done, you just add the two numbers and use the result to set the value of the last CEdit (that should be either inactive of read-only) with `SetDlgItemInt`.

If you want to accept floating point, you should read the values with `SetDlgItemText` and write them with `SetDlgItemText` and process the conversions to/from double by hand.

What I mean is that you will not have to use the `OnEnChangeEditx` notifications but do all the stuff in the `OnBnClickedButton1` one.

As you have not shown your current code, I cannot say more here...